# XSD to HTML Conversion?

Tags: java, jsp, jaxb, xsom

strong textHello guys! Is there any way to convert an XSD file to an HTML file...what i am trying to achieve here is parse an XSD file and based on that give the user a form where in he can fill in the details...and finally i want to create an XML file by binding that data...For example
Consider the following XSD..

```
<xs:element name="Collection">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name ="books">
           <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="book" type="bookType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
              </xs:sequence>
           </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="bookType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="ISBN" type="xs:long"/>
    <xs:element name="price" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This should give me an HTML form like this

```
Collection:
Books
Book1:---TextBox---
Name:---TextBox---
ISBN:---TextBox---
Price:---TextBox---
Book2
Name:---TextBox---
ISBN:---TextBox---
Price:---TextBox---
```

If there is a choice then it should give the user a redio group etc...
any help will be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

XSL Transformations are often used to translate XML into something else: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Comment: +1 - this is probably the best way to do this.  The OP will need to read up on XSLT and figure out the transforms needed to generate the HTML in the form he desires.

Answer (score 0):

This site is doing something similar:

http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/formGenerator4.html